# Why reassigning an object defined in the outer function to a same variable name as declared outside is giving error?

Tags: javascript

Why `typeof` of `b` is  undefined in the below code?

```
var b = function() {}

var a = function() {
var b = b
console.log('typeof function_b:', typeof b) 
}
a()
```

Comment: You can choose the dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're initialising a new variable inside the `a` function scope with the declaration `var b`.

`var b` gets initialised and ran before the value gets assigned (`b = b`), so it is assigning the just-initialised empty value to itself.

To alter the output, you can just skip the `var` declaration and `typeof b` outputs "function":

```
var b = function() {}

var a = function() {
    b = b;
    console.log('typeof function_b:', typeof b); // Outputs "function"
}
a();
```

Comment: Now, obviously the `b = b` does nothing except assign the "global" `b` to itself.

Comment: @RocketHazmat That's right. But it's there to demonstrate the variable scoping in JavaScript functions.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the variable first get declared (`var b`), and then assigned `b = b`. After declaring it, it is `undefined` in that scope, so you're assigning `undefined` to it.